# query is slower after adding index

Tags: postgresql

I have a books table in a postgres database that has a user_id column. When there was no index, querying all the books with a certain user_id took `0.607 ms`

```
lesson4=# select * from books where user_id = 5;

Time: 0.607 ms
```

I then created an index like this

```
lesson4=# create index user_idx on books (user_id);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 43.288 ms
```

I then ran the same query and it took more than double the time

```
lesson4=# select * from books where user_id = 5;

Time: 1.397 ms
```

Note, there are only a few rows in the database. Not sure if that has an impact.

Did I create the index correctly? Why is it running slower now?

Comment: The magic constant for queries is half a second. If it takes longer than that, users will notice. They will _not_ notice a difference between half a millisecond and 1.4 milliseconds. A millisecond can generally be considered "noise" in query land, you may well find variations of that order even under the same conditions. Test with real data _then_ start worrying.

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for both? Under what test conditions was this done? How repeatable/stable are the results across repeated runs? What're `random_page_cost` and `seq_page_cost`? What's the disk I/O subsystem like? Does the index fit in RAM? Does the whole table fit in RAM? PostgreSQL version? So many details needed.

Comment: I too would consider the difference between 0.6ms and 1.4ms to be an inaccuracy from measuring. Run each statement at *least* 10 times and then take the average of those runtimes. You also need to make sure that absolutely nothing else is running on the computer - even opening a Word document (or starting the browser, or a background service that just woke up, or another query, or ...) could influence a measurement in that range.

Comment: Funny, it could even be that in this case the actual query is just as fast, but that the planner has more work to do. (IIRC pg-9.4 will have an explain option for this)

Comment: The difference between 0.6 and 1.4ms is unlikely to be meaningful.  How many times did you repeat this experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is a little over three times as slow.  Here's what is probably happening, assuming:

1. The table is about 10 pages in length
2. The table and the index both fit in RAM
3. You are pulling a few records from different pages, but far less than 10% of the table.

The planner determines the index might help, so it does an index scan. This requires a tree search through the index, followed by a sequential scan through the relevant pages.

Without the index, you do a sequential scan through the ten pages, find the answer.  Not only is the second faster, it is simpler.

This is why on PostgreSQL, indexes aren't the magic answer for performance problems.  Usually it is worth noting that performance is approaching the danger zone before even thinking about adding an index.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/storage-page-layout.html, it says that a page by default is about 8kb in size, so can I assume 80kb can be held in RAM? May I ask how you got the 10 pages number?

Comment: Usually on very small tables, PostgreSQL will ignore indexes for querying.  I got the 10 pages based on the fact that there are optimizer hooks based on table size.  The actual amount could be more or less depending on actual data.

Comment: Keep in mind, of course, *nothing* beats a sequential scan on a single page table :-)